# NSRunningApplication 'terminated' not Observable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I'm building a program that launches another program and is then supposed to monitor it, and take action if it terminates. When the application is launched, I can get an instance of **NSRunningApplication** from **NSWorkspace**.

Now, the documentation states that **NSRunningApplication** has the property 'terminated' that is key-value observable. I've tried implementing:

```
[browserInstance addObserver:self 
                          forKeyPath:@"terminated"
                             options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                             context:NULL];
```

And:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath 
                      ofObject:(id)object 
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context  
{  

        NSLog(@"observeValueForKeyPath");  
        if ([keyPath isEqual:@"terminated"])  
        {  
            NSLog(@"terminated");  
        }  
}
```

but I never see the **observeValueForKeyPath** method get tripped. Does anyone know how to make this work, if it is possible? I haven't been able to find any specific examples anywhere online.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?

Comment: If anyone with edit permissions sees this can they please change the title to something a little more relavent, like "NSRunningApplication 'terminated' not Observable"

Answer (score 17):

Have you tried the keyPath "isTerminated"?

Notice in the documentation for [NSRunningApplication](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html), the property `terminated` specifies the getter `isTerminated`, rather than the default getter `terminated`. (Which makes sense, as a Boolean property "is" or "isn't")

This suggests there may be a bug in obj-c property parsing, where the name of the getter is used for the KVO path.

Comment: Thanks! You must observe on `isTerminated`. You my man, have eagle eyes. Excellent catch. Have 50 point-thingys

Comment: +1 I had this exact question with the `finishedLaunching` key. Just what I needed, ta!

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using:

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter];

    // Install the notifications.

    [center addObserver:self 
               selector:@selector(appLaunched:) 
                   name:NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification 
                 object:nil];
    [center addObserver:self 
               selector:@selector(appTerminated:) 
                   name:NSWorkspaceDidTerminateApplicationNotification 
                 object:nil];
```

And then implementing the **appLaunched** and **appTerminated** methods.

Answer (score 0):

The “is it plugged in” question: You've verified that `browserInstance` is not `nil`, right?

Comment: I've stepped through the code a few times to make sure everything is set properly. I don't think there's an issue there.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Apple's [Technical Note 2050: Observing Process Lifetimes Without Polling](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2050/_index.html).

[**TN2050**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2050/_index.html) covers Apple's recommended methods for observing the lifetime of processes you launch, and those launched by others.

Comment: Yes but this does not answer why KVO is not working on NSRunningApplication `terminated`

Comment: I recommend using one of the methods provided by Apple in TN2050. The documented methods deal with edge cases and are Apple's recommended solution.

Comment: Note that TN2050 was last revised 2008-09-10

Comment: Unless TN2050 has been superseded, it remains best practice for at least C development.